# Clicking a drop down menu (trigged by mouse hover) with selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to click (with selenium) a drop down menu that only show it's options if the mouse hovers it. Moreover, each option is a javascript.

I tried to use Select (from webdriver) and the following code, but had no success:

```
options = Options()
#options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')

capabilities = options.to_capabilities()
capabilities['acceptInsecureCerts'] = True

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options, desired_capabilities=capabilities)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
driver.switch_to.frame(1)
button = driver.find_element(By.NAME,'link5')
```

---

The action consists of clicking at the drop down menu and select one of the options.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
button = driver.find_element(By.NAME,'link5')
hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button)
hover.perform()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='menuItemText2']"))).click()
```

**Explanation:** To achieve this, your automation script should imitate human actions. i.e. first, mouse hover the menu  **Relatórios** (In selenium, this can be achieved using `ActionChains` class as in the code above). After this click on the menu item once its visible(using `visibility_of_element_located` method) as in code above.